# Windows Bridge for iOS and Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, winobjc

I have an app developed using Xamarin.iOS that i would like to port to Windows 10. I have read that is possible to use Windows Bridge to port app developed using Objective-C (WinObjC provides support for iOS API) to Windows 10 using [WinObj](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC) project.

It's possible to do the same with a project written in C# using Xamarin.iOS?

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with Xamarin.iOS you need to forget WinObjC. WinObjC is a bridge to write native windows apps using Objective-C. Since you're using C# you can write the interface using XAML and share your business logic between the apps easily.

Answer (score 0):

The WinObjC project is a bridge of Cocoa Touch, not a port, and it's real Objective-C. You would have to convert your C# code to Objective-C by hand, yes. Eventually you'll be able to use (mostly) the same source code on iOS and Windows!

Answer (score 0):

Using the Windows Bridge for iOS to bring your Xamarin.iOS App to Windows is not working. This only works with Full Objective-C Projects. Anyways you will be able to build your Windows App on top of Xamarin.iOS very fast when you have encapsulated it correctly. Then you just need to rebuild the UI and maybe implement some interfaces :)

Answer (score -1):

WinObjC is the Windows Bridge for iOS (previously known as ‘Project Islandwood’).

Windows Bridge for iOS (also referred to as WinObjC) is a Microsoft open source project that provides an Objective-C development environment for Visual Studio/Windows.

In addition, WinObjC provides support for iOS API compatibility.

The bridge is available to the open-source community now in its current state.

The iOS bridge as an open-source project under the MIT license. Given the ambition of the project, making it easy for iOS developers to build and run apps on Windows. Salmaan Ahmed has an in-depth post on the Windows Bridge for iOS http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/06/windows-bridge-for-ios-lets-open-this-up/ discussing the compiler, runtime, IDE integration, and what the bridge is and isn’t. Best of all, the source code for the iOS bridge is live on GitHub right now.

The iOS bridge supports both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 apps built for x86 and x64 processor architectures, and soon we will add compiler optimizations and support for ARM, which adds mobile support.